# Asus ZENBOOK UX330 UAK finger printdriver

Tags: drivers, asus, fingerprint-reader

Is it possible to install the finger print driver in Ubuntu 18 ?

```
mostafa@mostafa-UX330UAK:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58d1 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to install `fprintd`?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18, there are 17.04, 17.10, 18.04 and 18.10, 19.04, 19.20, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Visit [Supported devices](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html) in libfrint. If your device is not supported, you can [open an issue in their gitlab page](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues) to know if it can be supported and whether it is being worked on (check the current list of issues).

The `04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp.` is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Your fingerprint scanner is supported by `libfprint`.

Most likely it should work without any effort on Ubuntu 20.04.

There is no "Ubuntu 18" release.

Comment: I upgraded my Ubuntu to Ubuntu 20  and I added my index fingerprint but when I scan my finger I can't login !

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18 or 20, it is not like Windows. Regarding login it is another issue.